# How to stop polling in SignalR?

Tags: signalr

Is there any way to stop polling server in SignalR? I want to stop polling server if error occurs. Polling hubs is started with `$.connection.hub.start()`, so I assumed that it could be stopped with `$.connection.hub.stop()` or something like that. But it doesn't seem to work, polling continues even after calling `stop()`. Is there another way to stop pollling?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
 var connection = $.connection.hub;

chatHub.addMessage = function (message) {
      $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
    };

connection.error(function (error) {
 $('#messages').append('<li>' + "error connecting: closing connnection" + '</li>');
    connection.stop(); //This doesn't seem to work   
        });

connection.start();

</script>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you're using hubs you can stop the hub's connection:

```
$.connection.hub.stop();
```

Comment: has that syntax changed to $.connection.hub.connection.stop()? That's all that works for me.

Comment: No it hasn't. That hasn't changed

Comment: obviously my mix up, sorry for wasting your time, now it's time for me to read up on difference between stopping a connection on a particular hub, $.connection.myHub.stop(), and above. have an idea what but think I'll setup a sandbox so I know.

Comment: Hubs share a single connection.

Comment: what if you're NOT using hubs, does that mean it cannot be done ?

Comment: If you're using PersistentConnection then you can just stop the connection object...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly are you sure that is it necessary? If communication error occurs than obviously you want to retry it.

However, I looked into the source code and I mean that especially in error handler it is not possible call `.stop()` command. Respectively it has no effect because after handler function is finished than the communication is automatically reinitialized two second after.

See jquery.signalR.js (line 340):

```
$(instance).trigger("onError", [data]);

window.setTimeout(function () {
  poll(instance);
}, 2 * 1000);
```

I found one workaround: In handler function throw an exception, which cause that poll is not reinitialized:

```
connection.error(function (error) { //$.connection.hub.error()
  $('#messages').append('<li>' + "error connecting: closing connnection" + '</li>');
  throw "Close SignalR connection";
});
```