# Disable Blazor Server Kestrel keep-alive client-server communication

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, kestrel-http-server

I'm about to create a .net 6 Blazor server application hosted by Kestrel (within a docker container) which uses a custom timeout handling on client side. Once the application is not used for e.g. 30 minutes a dialog is displayed and the page needs a reload for further usage (and a new server connection).
For stopping the application (connection) I call "Blazor.disconnect();" on the client side.

This works in general but I've noticed that after calling Blazor.disconnect() and displaying the information message the client and the server are still exchanging keep-alive data like this which I also want to suppress to save resources and bandwidth:

*Sent a ping message to the client. [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext]*

*Sending payload: 3 bytes
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport]*

*Message received. Type: Binary, size: 3, EndOfMessage: True [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport]*

Is there a way to end this communication on client side (via JavaScript) or on server side without having to navigate away from the application page ?

Comment: This is native to Blazor / SignalR. If you disable it, Blazor functionality stops. 3 bytes every once in a while is very little.

Comment: I know but once the application is not used any more and timed out I see no sense in that and wanted to prevent that.

Comment: [possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8311923)?

Comment: I'm not really sure. At least "$.connection.hub.stop();" does not work this way. Perhaps it's a little bit different for using within a Blazor server app ?

Comment: I thought SignalR connection should be stopped by Blazor.disconnect() ?